# How to align a Checkbox and Text on the same line in HTML?

Tags: html

This is the code I currently have. How do I format the checkbox to be right after the word "email" and not on the next line.

```
<label for="opt">Check this box to subscribe to our monthly newsletter. You can unsubscribe at any time using the link at the bottom of our email.</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="opt" name="opt" value="true" checked>
```

```html
<label for="opt">Check this box to subscribe to our monthly newsletter. You can unsubscribe at any time using the link at the bottom of our email.</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="opt" name="opt" value="true" checked>
```

[image]

[More Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJhLT.png)

Comment: I've just added a code snippet to allow people to easily see, and work with, your code; as you can see in the demo the default behaviour of a `<label>` and an `<input>` element is to appear in-line. Can you add the relevant CSS that leads to the results you show in the image?

Comment: By default, the checkbox _will_ show up inline. We would need to see more code to understand why you're getting the attached picture.

Comment: Thanks. I added another picture of the code. Does that help?

Comment: make your label an `inline` element.

Comment: @Rod911 Does that mean adding <div> to the end of both lines?

Comment: @JD15 usually label and input elements are already inline, some css may have made either one block or inline-block, use css to make them inline again. `display: inline;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might set the display of the `label` to block. That means it will occupy the whole line for himself. The default display of label tag is inline. You can read about block level and inline tags [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp#:%7E:text=A%20block%2Dlevel%20element%20always,is%20a%20block%2Dlevel%20element.).

So you must set the display of your label tag to `inline` so the check box could come next to the text.

```css
.first {
  display: block
}

.second {
  display: inline
}
```

```html
<label class="first">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto modi earum laudantium quod facilis ullam eaque reprehenderit, hic autem deserunt dolor ratione animi. Dolor, voluptate!</label>
<input type="checkbox"><br/><br/>

<label class="second">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto modi earum laudantium quod facilis ullam eaque reprehenderit, hic autem deserunt dolor ratione animi. Dolor, voluptate!</label>
<input type="checkbox">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <input class="checkbox-form" type="checkbox" 
                    name="customer[note][Zanat][]" value="Drugi zanat:" />
       
                   <input class="drugi-zanat" type="text" 
                    name="customer[note][Zanat][]" placeholder="Dodaj..." autocorrect="off"
                    autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off"> 
        </div>
```

Comment: the code in this answer is not valid.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33242563)